# Job scheduling in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

The project in which I am working requires synchronization of data between MongoDB and SQL Server, so what is the best way for it? This synchronization should be handled by MongoDB side; does MongoDB support job scheduling?

I am new in MongoDB and I want to know few things about it. I know it is not an RDBMS but in case it is possible, then how?

Like we can write program in Oracle can we write in MongoDB. I mean directly in MongoDB, if no then which client side language can used?

Comment: Mongo DB does not support Job scheduling.You need that, you should use cron or windows scheduler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Vasanth said, MongoDB has no native job management.

As to which client side language: well that's entirely upto you.

You can always get get a prebuilt replicator like: http://code.google.com/p/tungsten-replicator/ that might do the job for you.

As further reference, this question maybe of help to you: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/125980/can-sql-server-and-mongo-be-used-together