# Update Collections in Mongo DB Automatically

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

So i am trying to create a View like SQL in Mongo dB.  Since i am aware that this cannot be directly achieved, i have created an aggregate function.  This complex aggregate function does exactly what i need to do and load the value in a new collection.

```
db.User.aggregate([
    {$limit:5}
     {$lookup: {
    from: "Interactions", 
    localField: "_id",
    foreignField: "userId",
    as: "InteractionsView"}
      },
  {$project: {

      "userCount": "$User.Count",
      .
      .
      . 
      . //(All fields i need are added here)

     "InteractionsView.Pages" : {
  $filter: {
         input: "$InteractionsView.Pages",
         as: "num",
         cond: { $gte: [ "$$num.Datetime", new Date("2015-06-14T20:15:31Z")] }
    }
  }
}},
{$out:"ReportView"}

])

  db.ReportView.find({});
```

This is good and the query works.. Now, since i cannot use Views, i am trying to update this collection frequently so that i can serve as a view. Is there any option like a scheduler that i can configure to run every 10 minutes or are  there any new out of box options available to do so?  or am i doing it completely all wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Though there is no built in support for scheduling tasks in mongodb. See [job scheduling in mongodb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13304979/job-scheduling-in-mongodb)

However, you can use Operating System level support (for ex Cronjobs in Linux) to schedule your task.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO this is a bad idea at all to project relational thinking to document store.

If query provided by you is limited to 5 documents and execution time is acceptable then I will suggest use cache server like redis to store results in a key-value shape with a TTL set to 5 minutes, or simply create a cache object on server.

In simplest form you could execute same query per request and utilise cache mechanism provide by database engine.

Thinking in performance creating new collection is always disk intensive,  reusing memory results will play faster and smoother.

Aby comments welcome!