# MongoDB Run query once a month

Tags: mongodb

I would like to run a simple query that resets a couple values in my database once a month. I could simply write a node app that would run 24/7 and executes said query once a month but that seems like a waste of resources. Is there a way to configure MongoDB to execute said query once a month on its own? Or maybe some other solution that would pose a compromise of the 2 solutions?

Comment: Try using https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule and setting it to run every 1st of the month and update the values in the database using below rule
"0 0 0 1 * *"

Comment: Yes, I have worked with node schedule before which is what I would be using if I would need to use a node app to reset the values. My question was aiming for any solutions that don't involve running a Node app 24/7 on a server

Answer (score 4):

You can done this by installing

> npm i node-cron

```
var cron = require('node-cron');
```

```
cron.schedule('* * * * *', () => {

  console.log('running a task every minute');

});
```

Run cron job on month example

```
var cron = require('node-cron');

 

cron.schedule('* * * Jan,Sep Sun', () => {

  console.log('running on Sundays of January and September');

});
```

> If a cron job has to run on th 15th of every month at 01:00 Hours, the
>   time is set in the following manner :

```
 cron.schedule('* 01 15 * *', () => { 
        // YOUR LOGIC  HERE.....
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use cron or windows scheduler. You can use [MongoDB-Cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb-cron)

```
import { MongoCron } from 'mongodb-cron';

const collection = db.collection('jobs');
const cron = new MongoCron({
  collection, // a collection where jobs are stored
  onDocument: async (doc) => console.log(doc), // triggered on job processing
  onError: async (err) => console.log(err), // triggered on error
});

cron.start();
```

Similar question was asked before for [MongoDB scheduling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13304979/job-scheduling-in-mongodb).